# Generating code with maven-jaxb2-plugin does not work with the same configuration after v0.12.0

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

The same pom.xml is working with maven-jaxb2-plugin v0.11 but not with v0.12.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <schemaInclude>*.wsdl</schemaInclude>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/jaxws/</bindingDirectory>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/target/jaxws/java</generateDirectory>
                <strict>false</strict>                  
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The reason is because after the fix#23 null is returned rather than "systemId" in the MavenCatalogResolver.java (line:64)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3003)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.resolver.tools.MavenCatalogResolver.getResolvedEntity(MavenCatalogResolver.java:64) at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver.resolveEntity(CatalogResolver.java:192)
```

What would be the right configuration for my pom.xml in order to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Please file an issue [here](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues) ans send me a sample project to reproduce (the best would be a pull request to [tests](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests).

I'll be fixing this ASAP.

I wonder how a passed `systemId` can be `null` but it's a bug anyway. Will be fixed ASAP, I just need a test project to reproduce.

**Update.**

The [0.12.2](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/releases/tag/0.12.2) release fixes the NPE you're reporting. However, I'm not sure that it fixes your build. It may well be that you have a different problem. I wonder how `systemId` can be null.

Please send me the reproducing project for further tests.

Generally it would be better for file bugs and issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues) rather than posting on SO.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, unfortunately i cannot share this project and i have no time now to create a sample project, as i am new to this, and my knowledge is limited. If i have some time in the near future i will try and send you a test that reproduces the issue. For now i have reverted back to 0.11.0. Thanks

Comment: @nicolas Try upgrading to 0.12.2.